# Self sizing cell makes views to stretch

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints

I tried to make self-sizing cells. I got it to work but with some bug. Which I think is because of wrong constraits. So I kindly ask you if you could look them.

Problem is that after scrolling in tableview, all my views are going to stretch. I thought that it would happen because of not setting height constraint but it seems not to be problem.

Illustration(pretty normal):

[image]

After scrolling and coming back up:

[image]

And these are my constraints for this view which all of them looks good to me:

[image]

And if you want to know how I made cells to resize, then like this:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 105//Because my row height is 105
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: "which all of them looks good to me" Really? To me they look truncated and illegible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this sort of thing happens, the implication is that you are not supplying sufficient constraints to size the cell's `contentView` from the inside out. You can readily confirm this using View Debugging to pause the app when you see your incorrectly sized cell; you will then be able to study the actual values of your constraints and see what the problem is.

**EDIT** Now that you've posted your constraints, it's easy to see what the problem is: There is nothing at all connecting your interface elements to the *bottom* of the `contentView`. But that is the whole point of self-sizing cells: you must have, as I already said, sufficient constraints running all the way from the top of the `contentView` to the bottom of the `contentView`. That is what determines the height — and so you are *not* determining it.

Comment: Also you've got some obvious problems with your image view. This could easily have something to do with what you're seeing.

Comment: Sorry I had totally wrong image in question. But I am gonna test your suggestion. But is it possible that borders and frames are causing this?

Comment: Thanks for posting the correct constraints. As I said in my answer, you are not supplying sufficient constraints. There is nothing here connecting us to the bottom of the `contentView`!

Comment: You were absolutely right. But I still managed to get it to work. I added bottom space constraints to `texView` and `imageView` to `contentView` and it did the trick.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see why. Maybe I have some misconception about UITextView.

Comment: Okay, I see why. It's because when you set `scrollEnabled` to `false`, you _do_ get an instrinsic content size.

Comment: Yep. You got it. I had to do it also because I want it to resize too in the feature.